# Нет перевода текста на странице "Предлагаемые правки"

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

Нет перевода некоторых фраз на странице "Предлагаемые правки".

[image: alt]

[image: cos]

Модальное окно без перевода и *"Learn more about the ..." - "Узнайте больше об очереди проверок"* в шапке страницы.

Предлагаю текст:

> Вы заработали доступ к очереди предлагаемых правок!
> Оценивайте предлагаемые изменения пользователями, у которых недостаточно репутации для вноса прямых изменений в сообщения других пользователей. Вы можете принимать, улучшать либо отклонять правки или удалять некачественные.
> Как работать с очередью:
>
> - Два пользователя должны подтвердить предложенные изменения, чтобы опубликовать правку.
> - Правки должны поддерживать оригинальные намерения автора вопроса. (?)
> - Отклоняйте правки, которые являются спамом, содержат попытку ответа на вопрос автора или явно ухудшают вопрос.
> - ...  *
>
> Продобнее о "Предлагаемые правки" в справку.

`*` - не могу предложить красочный вариант этого предложения, т.к. не на столько владею качественной речью :)

Comment: Также нет перевода на странице "Первые сообщения", и я предполагаю, что на остальных правках ситуация аналогичная.

Comment: Если есть вариант перевода, можете предлагать сразу через Traducir. Только нужно следовать утвержденным терминам, например "центр помощи" -> "справка"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переводы добавлены. Будут на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.4.20.39115.

P.S. Вы всегда можете предложить свои переводы на https://ru.traducir.win/